# I'm getting a no such method error: Receiver null. Tried calling: []("postId") flutter error

Tags: flutter, null, nosuchmethoderror

I've been searching since last night and today for a solution to this issue. I've come across many different variations of this problem, but none of the solutions seem to work for my mine.

I get that the receiver is coming back as null, but I don't understand why. When I look in Firebase, I can see the post that I'm trying to retrieve, it has a valid postId and a url. So I'm not understanding what I'm missing.

Can someone please help me figure this out? Please let me know if there's any other helpful information I should include.

This is the error message I received:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot>#08c05):
```

**PostScreenPage.dart**

```
import 'package:buddiesgram/pages/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:buddiesgram/widgets/PostWidget.dart';
import 'package:buddiesgram/widgets/ProgressWidget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PostScreenPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final String userId;
  final String postId;
  //List<Post> posts = [];
  
  PostScreenPage({
    this.userId,
    this.postId,
});

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: postsReference.document(userId).collection("usersPost").document(postId).get(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        if(!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        Post post = Post.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data);
        return Center(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.blue,), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),),
              title: Text("Posts", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
            body: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: post,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The error also pointed to the postId line below, in the error message

**PostWidget.dart**

```
factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return Post(
      postId: documentSnapshot["postId"],
      ownerId: documentSnapshot["ownerId"],
      likes: documentSnapshot["likes"],
      username: documentSnapshot["username"],
      description: documentSnapshot["description"],
      location: documentSnapshot["location"],
      url: documentSnapshot["url"],
    );
  }
```

Comment: It means `documentSnapshot` is `null` in the factory constructor. Print out `dataSnapshot.data` to see what it contains.

Comment: So I did that and got flutter: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'. So now that I know it's null in the factory constructer, why is that? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry it's not actually `null`. You're passing a `DocumentSnapshot` not a `Map`.

Comment: I have created an answer that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're treating the `DocumentSnapshot` like a `Map`. `[]` is not valid notation for a `DocumentSnapshot`. To fix this do:

```
factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  Map<String, dynamic> mapOfData = documentSnapshot.data;
    return Post(
      postId: mapOfData["postId"],
      ownerId: mapOfData["ownerId"],
      likes: mapOfData["likes"],
      username: mapOfData["username"],
      description: mapOfData["description"],
      location: mapOfData["location"],
      url: mapOfData["url"],
    );
  }
```

This code retrieves the `Map` data from the `DocumentSnapshot` with the `.data` getter before trying to access its fields.

Comment: So I applied this to the factory Post code and I ran it, but it's still giving the same error. Is there anything else I'm supposed to apply to my FutureBuilder?

Comment: What database are you using? Firestore?

Comment: Yes I'm using Firebase

Comment: Firestore or Realtime database? Both are options in Firebase.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I totally forgot about Realtime. I'm using Firestore

Comment: So I went back into my Firestore database and I deleted the existing posts I had created and then ran re-ran the app and created new posts. After creating them, I went to click on the post and still got the null error. Is there anything else I missed? @Christopher Moore

Comment: print  out what `mapOfData` is.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time out. I figured out it was a stupid misspell mistake. Sorry for waisting your time! btw your solution does work perfectly though.

Answer (score 0):

So after wasting so much time, I figured out it was totally my fault. A stupid misspell mistake. I put "usersPost" instead of "usersPosts". I missed that one s. Also @Christopher Moore's solution worked also. I tried his factory solution and my old factory solution and they both worked. So if you happen to come across this problem, spell check FIRST and then try his solution out. Thanks for everyones help!